# How to create a custom polygon fill pattern with only one icon?

Tags: qgis, icon

I have created a custom SVG icon in QGIS. When I zoom in it repeats the shape over and over within the polygon. I want to only see one icon even when I zoom in. For example, the icon is a single diamond, but when I zoom in it fills the poly with twenty diamonds....I just want to see one large diamond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose **Centroid Fill**, then set **SVG marker** as a centroid. If you want a border, you have to create another layer with a simple fill and transparent polygon with black border.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to have the icon "fill" to the edges of the polygon as you zoom in and out? Thanks.

Comment: Here is a method that gives you an icon that scales to the width of the polygon. It's certainly not perfect, but if your polygons are simple shapes this may work for you.  
  
As dmh126 suggested, use Centroid Fill with SVG Marker. Click the menu icon next to Size, choose Edit, paste this into the Expression String Builder:  
  
bounds_width($geometry)  
  
To change the icon size, add a scaling factor. For example this will give you icons that are 75% as wide as the polygon:  
  
bounds_width($geometry)*0.75